# Enabling font ligatures in JetBrains IDEs on non JetBrain Runtime

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I run some JB IDEs (Idea, PyCharm) **intentionally** not with JB runtime but with the JRE provided by the system and want to keep it so.

Is it possible to override the JRE check by some kind of setting (not switching to JB-JRE), so that the ligatures check-box will be available again?

Comment: sounds like something you should ask jetbrains first, instead of posting to SO first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the comment in [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-183380):

> That's by design - JetBrains Runtime has performance optimizations related to text layout, that OpenJDK/Oracle JDK don't contain. Without them using ligatures can lead to performance problems.

The check in the code is performed [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/1af811e3c1cfdc7746dfdc859f9c40332bb55487/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/application/options/colors/AbstractFontOptionsPanel.java#L339):

```
myEnableLigaturesCheckbox.setEnabled(!readOnly && SystemInfo.isJetBrainsJvm);
```

Where `SystemInfo.isJetBrainsJvm` is [defined as](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/61fe43f206b656bceed1317a0c8a029fce5964c2/platform/util/src/com/intellij/openapi/util/SystemInfo.java#L41):

```
public static final boolean isJetBrainsJvm = containsIgnoreCase(JAVA_VENDOR, "JetBrains");
```

So, you either need to patch IntelliJ IDEA code to accept other runtime vendors or patch the JDK to report `JetBrains` vendor. There is no easy way to override it.